# How to properly parse a dictionary array

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I'm trying to parse the observed wind speed value from the following json as a float (5.586995). The code below returns the value as an array (["5.586995"]). Is this the best approach in Swift 3? Any help is much appreciated.

```
{  
   "properties":{  
      "platform_type_description":"Weather and Sea Surface Data",
      "parameters":[  
         {  
            "id":"wind_speed",
            "units":"m s-1",
            "depth":{  
               "value":"0",
               "units":"m"
            },
            "observations":{  
               "times":[  
                  "2017-04-21T14:08:00"
               ],
               "values":[  
                  "5.586995"
               ],
               "quality_levels":[  
                  "3"
               ]
            }
         },
         {  
            "id":"wind_speed_of_gust",
            "units":"m s-1",
            "depth":{  
               "value":"0",
               "units":"m"
            },
            "observations":{  
               "times":[  
                  "2017-04-21T14:08:00"
               ],
               "values":[  
                  "7.39788"
               ],
               "quality_levels":[  
                  "3"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

func getWind() {       

    let url = URL(string: "http://windapp.dev/")!

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in

        if error == nil {
            if data != nil {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]

                    guard let properties = json["properties"] as? [String:Any],
                    let parameters = properties["parameters"] as? [Any],
                    let windspeedDict = parameters[0] as? [String:Any],
                    let observationsWindSpeedDict = windspeedDict["observations"] as? [String:[String]]

                        else {
                            print("Error!")
                            return
                        }

                        for (key, value) in observationsWindSpeedDict {
                            if key == "values" {
                                print(value)
                            }
                        }


                        } catch {}

                            }
                    }  else {
                        print("Error: Couldn't connect to server")
                        }
            }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: This depends on your data model. Do you ever expect to have more or less than one value?

Comment: Show the code you have so far. If you got the array cast the first item to Double.

Comment: @PedroCastilho No. The value returned will always be a single float value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected result, since the JSON contains the float value as a value of an array with only one element and you make value the whole array when iterating through your dictionary.

If you know your data will always look exactly like this, you should make your parsing function more specific and don't save any values as Any. If this is a response from your own backend and you think your project will get quite complex, you could use a 3rd party service (for example Swagger, though it has quite a few bugs) enabling you to write a more abstract specification of your JSON and generate both server and client side code automatically. However, I would only recommend this for large and complex projects.

Other than that I think your method is an optimal approach for parsing this response.